# How to close a parent form when child gets opened

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a form1 form2 and form3 now i want to open form2 at the same place of form1 and the form1 should get closed/hide. similar for form2 and form3.

How can i do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the parent form in the constructor of the child form. Store the reference in a member field or property, and when the child form opens, close the parent.